# making a universal batch script for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I'm writing a batch script that's gonna be used by multiple windows machine.  Each windows machine has a different user account name, ie: computerA,computerB, etc.  Is there a way to write my script to go to the default desktop path for windows 7.  Usually its C:/Users/(Whatever the User account name is)/Desktop

I'm trying to see if there's something I can replace for (Whatever the user account name) so that this will work for any windows 7 machine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User the `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable:

So the desktop path would be %USERPROFILE%\Desktop

Comment: Thank you!  Exactly what I needed!  Do you have any links to reference material for more info on writing batch stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Use the %userprofile% variable

```
%userprofile%\desktop
```

%userprofile% variable will expand to something like  C:\Users\Username